# Google map + places near to current location from SQL Server with haversine formulae

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a list of general stores that are near to the current map location.

Everything works fine but I just realised no matter where I pan the map to, a lot of stores that are no where near to the current map location gets call from my SQL Server DB.

Example:

I have a store which resides in Germany in the DB:

```
Venue        Venue_Lat       Venue_Lng
Bookstore    51.165712       10.451547
```

I am using the Haversine formulae in my Stored Procedure [GetNearbyLocations] to retrieve the stores that are suppose to be within 50 miles of the current location, say I pass in a current location as USA with a radius of 50 miles:

```
Radius: 50
USA Lat: 38.5554745
USA Lng: -95.6649999
```

The store in Germany gets called as well even though its not within the 50 miles radius. I understand and accept that the formulae is not 100% accurate but is this usual? Can anyone please kindly advice on this. Thanks.

A portion of the SProc:

```
DECLARE @intMilesModifier int
SET @intMilesModifier = 3959

    SELECT .... some fields,
     [Venue_Lat],
     [Venue_Long],
    (@intMilesModifier*acos(cos(radians(@dmlLat))*cos(radians(Venue_Lat))*cos(radians(Venue_Long)-radians(@dmlLng))+sin(radians(@dmlLat))*sin(radians(Venue_Lat)))) AS distance
    FROM  [Stores] a 
    WHERE (@intMilesModifier*acos(cos(radians(@dmlLat))*cos(radians(Venue_Lat))*cos(radians(Venue_Long)-radians(@dmlLng))+sin(radians(@dmlLat))*sin(radians(Venue_Lat)))) < @Radius
```

Answer (score 1):

This PHP/MySQL PDO SQL statement uses the formula (6371 for kilometers,3959 for miles)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM gbstn HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);//coordinate of center
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);//coordinate of center
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
```

You will need to modify this to suit

**EDIT**
You have extra calculations in your formula. I have edited my statement to show what you should have. I removed [] brackets and `a` from `[Stores] a`, don't  need alias, but cant run query as I dont have SQL Server.

```
"SELECT  Venue_Lat,Venue_Long,(@intMilesModifier * acos( cos( radians(@dmlLat) ) * cos( radians( Venue_Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Venue_Long ) - radians(@dmlLng) ) + sin( radians(@dmlLat) ) * sin( radians( Venue_Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Stores HAVING distance < @Radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20"
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake but actually I was using the Harvesine formulae previously which yields the same result, anyway I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks. I think the formula is correct. Is it possible for you to try it out on your side just to ensure that the error lies on my end?

Comment: I have modified code which should run. I cant run it as I don't have SQL server